# ¿Es posible revertir las calificaciones negativas a una respuesta que es correcta?

Tags: discusión

Me sucedió en una respuesta que di sobre una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36973/java-singleton-en-la-misma-clase/36978#36978) de Java y el patrón de diseño Singleton.

Di un enlace con la prueba de que mi respuesta es correcta, y sin embargo he recibido dos -1.

**¿Existe algún tipo de mediación? ¿Alguna forma en que un moderador pueda revisar?**

Este es mi caso, pero pueden haber otros o presentarse en un futuro.

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con el punto mas general (estoy notando muchos votos muy cuestionables: votos a favor para respuestas muy malas, o votos negativos para respuestas correctas)... y puede ser frustrante cuando te votan negativo sin explicación. Pero en este caso, hay por lo menos 2 aspectos de tu respuesta que no son del todo correctos (*el singleton siempre se obtiene de una función estática* y *la función del singleton es abstraer la instancia*), y aunque no estés de acuerdo con ellos, por lo menos hay que agradecer a los 2 usuarios que dejaron comentarios bajo tu respuesta al respecto.

Comment: @JCorrea, en mi caso **también recibí dos -1 me parece ridículo, aún más que la única respuesta no tiene ni explicación**, algo que he notado aquí es que existen ciertos grupos los cuales se apoyan entre sí, no podemos discutir que el optar dar puntos -1 o +1 son cuestiones subjetivas, en fin.

Comment: ¿Existe algún tipo de mediación? ¿Alguna forma en que un moderador pueda revisar? Como comento el asignar puntuación es determinado por los usuarios, los moderadores no pueden tener la tarea de revisar porque en algunas ocasiones revisarían algo que tal vez no conocen y no podrían determinar si es correcta o no la respuesta ლ(⚆Ĺ̯⚆ლ)

Comment: Vale, sobre mi caso concreto ya me comentaron mis errores y reconozco que tienen razón. Sobre los casos donde realmente hayan votos negativos en una respuesta que es correcta, parece que no es posible moderarlo y dependemos del juicio racional de los demás.

Comment: @Elenasys: En el caso de tu respuesta, los votos negativos fueron acompañados de comentarios que explicaban el porqué, asi que no veo que sea ridículo. Y en el caso de la otra respuesta a la que te refieres, estoy de acuerdo contigo, y por eso le di voto negativo también. Pero parece que soy el único que lo ha hecho. Si no te parece útil su respuesta, puedes votarle negativo también. En esta pregunta en particular, veo que todos los que recibieron votos negativos, por lo menos se les dejó una explicación. En realidad, yo los envidio a uds., porque yo no he tenido este lujo con mis respuestas.

Comment: a mi me ha pasado lo mismo en esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32927/14088) en la que también votaron negativamente a @Elenasys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los moderadores no podemos revisar quién ha realizado los votos sobre alguna publicación. Tampoco intervenimos en los procesos normales de votación de publicaciones (a favor/en contra). Tampoco intervenimos en caso que una publicación tiene muchos votos.

El sistema de votación es bien sencillo.

### Preguntas

- A favor: Esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara.
- En contra: Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil

### Respuestas

- A favor: Esta respuesta es útil
- En contra: Esta respuesta no es útil

Los motivos del uso de los votos son muy subjetivos. Entre ellos, puedo mencionar los que yo considero para el caso de respuestas (puesto que es la idea de tu pregunta):

- La respuesta es concisa y resuelve el problema: a favor.
- La respuesta es concisa, resuelve el problema y brinda ejemplos extra: a favor.
- La respuesta es concisa, resuelve el problema, brinda ejemplos y amplía la explicación para otros casos: a favor.
- La respuesta muestra código con comentarios para explicar el problema y la solución: a favor.
- La respuesta me ayudó a llegar a mi solución: a favor.
- La respuesta explica de todo menos el problema y/o la solución: en contra.
- La respuesta explica la solución pero contiene errores: neutro o en contra. Depende de cuán equivocado esté el autor.
- La respuesta contiene graves errores teóricos que pueden causar confusión a quienes revisan el sitio: en contra, si se puede, voto a eliminar<sup>1</sup>.
- La respuesta provee código que no compila: en contra.
- La respuesta puede estar equivocada pero no conozco del tema: neutro.
- La respuesta es grandiosa según los votos y comentarios que veo pero no conozco del tema: neutro.

En tu caso, tienes un voto a favor y un voto en contra por tu respuesta. Significa que alguien considera que tu respuesta es útil y otra persona considera que no lo es. Adicional a eso, para tu caso particular, hay un comentario que intenta explicar por qué puedes tener un error en tu respuesta.

¿Qué deberías hacer si has recibido un voto en contra? Pues primero que nada mantener la calma. Puede que a alguien simplemente le guste votar en contra o que tu respuesta tenga algún problema. Usualmente, los usuarios que votan en negativo tienden a explicar el por qué de su voto (tal como parece haberte sucedido, no es 100% certero que quien deje un comentario sea realmente el autor del voto negativo). Revisa el comentario por si hay algo que puedas corregir. Puede que la otra persona se encuentre equivocada, puede que seas tú quien está equivocado. No estaría mal que revises tu respuesta. Si consideras que todo está bien, entonces no te preocupes y continúa con tus cosas. Si ves que hay más votos en contra, es más probable que debas corregir algo en tu respuesta.

---

<sup>1</sup> Dado que soy moderador, me restrinjo de votar a eliminar una respuesta a menos que se trate de spam, convertir en comentario o convertir en edición de otra publicación.